# How to do a Salesforce query using apache camel related to the field CreatedDate?

Tags: java, apache-camel, salesforce

I am doing a salesforce query to fetch certain records based on conditions imposed on the field `ID` and `CreatedDate` using apache camel. This is the `toD` statement

```
.toD("salesforce:query?sObjectQuery=Select Id, Name, CreatedDate from Account where Id > '' and CreatedDate > 2019-01-03T12:12:27.000+0000 order by CreatedDate, Id limit 10&rawPayload=true")
```

This returns this error response

```
org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException: {errors:[{"errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY","message":"\nCreatedDate > 2019-01-03T12:12:27.0000000 order by CreatedDate, Id limit\n                                        ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:101\nline 1:101 no viable alternative at character ' '","fields":null}],statusCode:400}
```

Looks like it is ignoring the `+` in the Created Date. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Expected date & Datetime formats are here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Dot for milliseconds is not accepted and if you don't need timezone - drop the part with "+" too. Zulu time is closest to what you have, go with 2019-01-03T12:12:27Z ?