# How can I filter a SOQL query in a Python script after a specific datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, google-bigquery, salesforce, soql

I'm trying to select all records from the OPPORTUNITY object that are greater than a variable DateTime. However, I can't figure out how. This is in a Python script using the simple_salesforce package. I believe the issue is either that I am missing the millisecond and +0000 timezone specification in my "max_date" parameter, which I retrieve from a BigQuery table, or that I'm not passing in my max_date parameter as a correct datatype.

My example code that does not work:

```
max_date = '2020-08-11T17:41:29'

SF_QUERY = ("""
  SELECT Id,
  CreatedDate
  FROM Opportunity
  WHERE CreatedDate > %s
  """ % max_date)
```

Where the CreatedDate field is formatted like so:

```
2019-10-31T16:01:19.000+0000
```

The query returns the error

```
 Response content: [{'message': "line 8:57 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>'", 'errorCode': 'MALFORMED_QUERY'}]
```

If I add quotes around the %s, to make it '%s', then I get the error

```
Response content: [{'message': "\n  AND BU_Last_Stage_Changed_Date__c >\n      ^\nERROR at Row:8:Column:7\nvalue of filter criterion for field 'BU_Last_Stage_Changed_Date__c' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes", 'errorCode': 'INVALID_FIELD'}]
```

Thanks for any help.

Referenced documentation:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301323/passing-a-variable-in-soql-select-statement-with-python-and-simple-salesforce
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#format_datetime

Comment: From the last link you posted, it seems the datetime should be '2020-08-11 17:41:29'

Comment: That format doesn't work, either as a string or datetime. I tried passing it into the SOQL query and received the same error. This was the format I used:

```2020-08-11 17:41:29```
```<class 'datetime.datetime'>```

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/q/63081281/313628

Comment: Thanks eyescream, that does. I actually just found that solution myself minutes before you commented from the post https://codecracksblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/15/how-to-use-datetime-in-dynamic-soql-query-where-condition/.

I simply needed to append a "Z" onto the end of my datetime string for SOQL to use it in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to append a "Z", short for Zulu time, which indicates UTC, to the end of my datetime string. The dynamic variable %s should not have quotes. Example:

```
max_date = '2020-08-10T17:41:29' # in prod, pull this data from BigQuery
max_date = max_date + "Z"

SF_QUERY = ("""
  SELECT Id,
  CreatedDate
  FROM Opportunity
  WHERE CreatedDate > %s
  """ % max_date)
```